# Continuous function existence

Tags: continuity

Prove that there is at most one continuous function on $[0,2]$ that satisfies:

$$v(x)=f(x)+\int_0^2 e^{-(x-y)^2} \cos(0.3v(y)) \, dy$$

I don't know how to estimate this integral...

Comment: So $f$ is known and the existence of $v$ is to be shown?

Comment: This is exactly as my assignment is written. There is also a hint to "estimate and apply the mean value theorem"

Comment: @MichaelHardy: **at most** one.  So existence is not to be shown, but uniqueness (assuming existence) is.

Comment: I'd have written "at most one continuous function $v$ on $[0,2]$", making it clear that $v$, not $f$ was the function whose uniqueness is to be shown.

Comment: Yes, that would be good, but existence and uniqueness of $f$ given $v$ is too trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two solutions, 
$$v_1(x) - v_2(x) = \int_0^2 e^{-(x-y)^2} (\cos(0.3 v_1(y)) - \cos(0.3 v_2(y)))\ dy$$

Now $\cos(.3 v_1(y)) - \cos(.3 v_2(y) = -.3 \sin(.3 s) (v_1(y) - v_2(y))$ for some $s$ between $v_1(y)$ and $v_2(y)$. Only quite obvious estimates of 
$\exp(-(x-y)^2)$ and $|\sin(s)|$ are needed ...
you should get $|v_1(x) - v_2(x)| \le c \max_y |v_1(y) - v_2(y)|$ with $c < 1$.

Comment: So we select anything we want for the exp part to come up with a bound?

Comment: And how does the final result prove that there is only one function?

Comment: Not "anything we want" - something that is obviously $\ge e^{-(x-y)^2}$.

Comment: If $t \le ct$ where $0 < c < 1$ and $t \ge 0$, what can you conclude?